# Extract lines where a character match in 3rd column

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I need to extract the lines where my 3rd column is equal to `38`.

I am trying the following command:

```
awk '{printf "$3=38"}' file
```

Sample file contents:

```
TRINITY_DN66807_c0_g1_i1    4   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   TTTAAGAAAATTACAGCCTGAACTAGATGAATTGCAAAAACTCATAGGCAAAAAGGAAGAAGAAATTGGATACGT *
TRINITY_DN66871_c0_g1_i1    4   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   AAGAGGACATAGAAACTGTGATGATAATAGTATTGCTCTACTATTTCCTATAGCTCAGTTATTCAGCTGTCAGTC *
TRINITY_DN66847_c0_g1_i1    0   38  2520299 37  274M    *   0   0   CTCTCCTAGGATGCAGGATGGCCTCTTGCCACCTACACCCTTCTTCATGGGTTCGGCCCTTGGTCAACTAAAGGA *   XT:A:U  NM:i:0  X0:i:1  X1:i:0  XM:i:0  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  MD:Z:274
TRINITY_DN66836_c0_g1_i1    0   38  21725268 37 733M    *   0   0   TAGATGATGAAACTGGGTTGACCCTTGTTCCTAAGACTCAGTCCAGAGAGTCCTGGACTTTGCACTTTGGTTAGATGCCCCTGCCCCTCCCGCCAGCGCTGAGGAGGAATCACGCAGGCCTGAACAGAACATTCAGGTGATCCTATGAAG  *   XT:A:U  NM:i:0  X0:i:1  X1:i:0  XM:i:0  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  MD:Z:733
```

Comment: `awk '$3==38' file` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `{printf "$3=38"}'` you tell awk to print literal `$3=38` when a line is found. You need to use a *condition*, that is, an expression outside of braces.

Use

```
awk '$3 ~ /^38$/'  file
```

See [demo online](https://ideone.com/tYWsME). The `$3 ~ /^38$/` is a regex matching check, Field 3 value is tested against `^38$` regex that matches a whole string eequal to `38`.

Or, use a simple string equality comparison (since `38` is a static text):

```
awk '$3 == "38"'  file
```